# Rails find all Customers that have exactly 1 Order

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a data model where a `Customer` has many `Orders`. I now need to extract all of the customers that have only placed 1 order and I am scratching my head trying to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
Customer.joins(:orders).group(:id).having("count(orders.id) = 1")
```

this will create a query like:

> SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" INNER JOIN "orders" ON
>   "orders"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" GROUP BY id HAVING
>   count(orders.id) = 1

**You would get all of the `customers` that have placed exactly 1 `order`.**

Answer (score 1):

To avoid ambiguous reference to the ID field, this would be used:

```
Customer.joins(:orders).group("customers.id").having("count(orders.id) = 1")
```

which would generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."customer_id" =
"customers"."id" GROUP BY customers.id HAVING count(orders.id) = 1
```

Comment: There would not be any ambiguous reference as ActiveRecord handles it correctly. It maps it to the model whose records you are fetching. See the SQL query generated in my answer.

Comment: I ran a SQL statement comparative to yours and a comparative ActiveRecord query against one of my applications. Both threw ambiguous errors. But I use Postgres, it might be different in SQLite or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Customer` and `Order` are `ActiveRecord` classes and consider you have a code line 
belongs_to :customer in your Order class definition. And also consider that Order table have a `foreign_key` or index column named `customer_id` do as below to get this Customer objects.

```
Customer.joins(:orders).where("count(orders.id) = 1")
```